# SQL Server 2008 hosting recommendations

Tags: sql-server, shared-hosting

I am currently working on a project that is hosted at GoDaddy and it has a large database.  (Periodically inserting millions of rows).  It keeps filling the transaction logs and since GoDaddy sets the SQL user up without permission to basically do anything, I cannot truncate it.  The 200mb database max is not ideal either.  A VPS isn't in the cards for this company just yet, so I am stuck trying to find a shared hosting provider that office SQL Server 2008 only hosting.

Soooooo, my question is, does anyone know of a hosting company that does SQL Server 2008 hosting that they can vouch for and give high marks?

Cheers guys & gals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a long story short, the more resources you use, the less likely you will be able to use a shared service provider to meet your needs.  If you run a Google search, you will find numerous :)  However, at some point you will need to get some dedicated resources if you plan on using SQL Server.

It sounds like you are trying to save costs, which is totally understandable, but as the old saying goes "you pay cheap, you pay twice".

Comment: You are indeed correct about the costs, and if it was my decision they would be hosting the environment themselves or using a VPS.

I was just trying to see if anyone had any recommendations for MSSQL2008 hosting opposed to me just searching for random, and probably, fraudulent Google result based reviews.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from.  I was just trying to give you a real-world view having some experience with discount hosting providers. One idea might be to try out amazon's ec2 service. It's not as simple to configure as your typical hosting provider, but they do support SQL express which allows up to 4gb.  In any case, good luck. Maybe someone else will have a good hosting provider to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

DiscountASP.NET looks like a good option for a problem I'm working on at the moment which has similar requirements.  They start you off with 500MB of space (+1GB TLog), and you can sign up for more.

Disclaimer: I haven't signed up with them yet, but I've been looking at some of the alternatives, and I keep heading back...